# Changing $ref in Swashbuckle Swagger Generation for response object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm producing a swagger for a simple api that returns an object which correctly generates the swagger response similar to the below. My question is, is it possible to change the definition from myCustomerMadeUpResponse to customerResponse.

```
"responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/myCustomerMadeUpResponse"
```